# Selecting parent's next sibling's children in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an illustration of a part of my DOM:

[image]

I want to trigger an effect on div with class `des` (which is in an odd `div`) on click event of `div` with class `but` (which is in the previous even `div`)

How can I select `des` from `but`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trivially, if `this` is the clicked `.but` element:

```
$(this).parent().next().children('.des')
```

This does assume that there are no other elements in the way, i.e. that the `.even` and `.odd` elements are immediate siblings, and that `.but` and `.des` are immediately children of their respective `.even` and `.odd` ancestors.

Less efficiently, but guaranteed to work with any arbitrary number of additional (non-matching) elements in the tree would be:

```
$(this).closest('.even').nextAll('.odd').first().find('.des')
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your markup. Something like this should work, though:

```
$('.but').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('.even').next().find('.des');
});
```

Comment: for _absolute_ safety from intervening DOM elements you'd have to use `.nextAll('.odd').first()` instead of `.next()`